# How to access the values from strings.xml dynamically?

Tags: java, android

What I want to do is to get a specific text from `strings.xml` dynamically. I think it will involve to access an object variable dynamically.
There will be a function like:

```
public void getDynamicString(int level) {
  text.setText(R.string.levelText_+level);
}
```

And in `strings.xml` there will be `<string name="levelText_5">Text level 5</string>`

I would rather not create a list with all the text resources. Can one do this in Java/Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the method `getIdentifier(name, defType, defPackage)` of the Resources class to get the id of a resource by name. Then you can do a normal `getString(id)` from the same class.

**EDIT**: a bit of Googling revealed this: [this](http://www.anddev.org/tinytut_-_get_resources_by_name__getidentifier_-t460.html). You can find sample usage there.

Answer (score 0):

Try: `getResources().getString(R.id.stringId)`.

Comment: Yes, but the question is how to get that dinamically? I would have to concatenate somehow.

Comment: Perhaps, you can have an array of strings in which case you need not concatenate.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is call

```
this.getString(R.string.levelText_5)
```

If your in an area of the program in which you have access to a Context or Application, such as a ListAdapter call:

```
context.getString(R.string.levelText_5)
```

or

```
application.getString(R.string.levelText_5)
```

if you have no access to the context or application then call:

```
getResources().getString(R.String.levelText_5);
```

To do it dynamically call:

```
String name = "levelText_"+level;
int id = getIdentifier(name, "string", "com.test.mypackage");
getResources().getString(id);
```

Comment: yeah, but 5 will come as a parameter, in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at using [getIdentifier(String, String, String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) of the Resources class.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I fixed it using this

okey , whenever you want to access a string from strings.xml dynamically and what i mean by that is to avoid using getResources().getString(R.id.stringId) ,you create a string in which you can manipulate dynamically however you want in our case uriq ("stupid variable name") and then you create resource object which is in my example level_res and initialize it then you use this method called getIdentifier() which accepts your dynamic string as a parameter ,now u simply pass your ressource to the method getstring(mysttring)

```
 String uriq="level"+level_num;
 level_res=getResources();
 int mystring=getResources().getIdentifier(uriq,"string",getPackageName());
 String level=level_res.getString(mystring);
```

Comment: Can you explain your solution?

Comment: uriq represents the string that changes dynamically by channging level_num ,so all you need to do is use the method getIdentifier() to get the appropriate string

Comment: okey , whenever you want to access a string from strings.xml dynamically and what i mean by that is to avoid using getResources().getString(R.id.stringId) ,you create a string in which you can manipulate dynamically however you want in our case uriq ("stupid variable name") and then you create resource object which is  in my example level_res and initialize it then you use this method called getIdentifier() which accepts your dynamic string as a parameter ,now u simply pass your ressource to the method getstring(mysttring)

Comment: Ezio please add that information to your answer, not in the comments :)

Comment: ah sorry , i thought you wanted explanation xD