# Convert String containing an ID into an Integer-ID

Tags: android, string

I have a short question:

How is it possible to convert a String, containing the Id of a Drawable, which is

```
String idString = "R.drawable.bubblegum";
```

to an Integer,

```
idInt
```

so that I can use that ID for the reference of an image (, which is used in a SimpleAdapter)

So, to make an example, I can't do that:

```
bubble.setImageDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable(idString));
//not possible, cause idString is a String an not an Id/Int
```

So, I have the String that's containing the id, but unfortunately as a String.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to convert "R.drawable.bubblegum" to an int? This would be not possible.

Comment: @flash it is possible using `getIdentifier`

Comment: @flash: yes, I'm trying that. But didn't work till now.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

At least, I couldn't get a solution for this problem. It seems that there's no way to convert a String "R.id.mytext" into an integer like R.id.mytext that can be used in findViewById(R.id.myText).

Comment: Everybody who answered is missing the point. Assuming that you are simply trying to just reference the id of a resource that already exists as you write the code. But just a thought here, what if you do not know at all. Or maybe you are trying to assign an id. Such as Menuitem.add(int resId) ???  What to do in that case?

Answer (score 22):

Although this question is rather old already, the thing you're missing is that "id" and "drawable" are different resource types. So instead of

```
getResources().getIdentifier(stringId, "id", "my.Package");
```

it's

```
getResources().getIdentifier(stringId, "drawable", "my.Package");
```

You can also get package name with the activity context like `activityContext.getPackageName()`

```
/**
 * Returns Identifier of String into it's ID as defined in R.java file.
 * @param pContext
 * @param pString defnied in Strings.xml resource name e.g: action_item_help
 * @return
 */
public static int getStringIdentifier(Context pContext, String pString){
    return pContext.getResources().getIdentifier(pString, "string", pContext.getPackageName());
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Call `getIdentifier()` on the `Resources` object you get via `getResources()`, as seen in these StackOverflow questions:

- [Is possible in Android to findView by String id?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7015907/is-possible-in-android-to-findview-by-string-id)
- [Android findViewbyId with a variant string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6679434/android-findviewbyid-with-a-variant-string)
- [How to access R.string.xxx resources from a method by passing string 'xxx' as parameter to that method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7257615/how-to-access-r-string-xxx-resources-from-a-method-by-passing-string-xxx-as-pa)
- [Dynamically build a resource Identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5330231/dynamically-build-a-resource-identifier)
- [How to access the values from strings.xml dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6460778/how-to-access-the-values-from-strings-xml-dynamically)
- [Drawable resource using a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7544312/drawable-resource-using-a-variable)

among others.

Comment: When I do this: String stringId = "R.id.icon"; long intId = getResources().getIdentifier(stringId, "id", "my.Package"); Log.d("Test",intId+""); then LogCat displays 0. Wrong Way?

Answer (score 3):

You could try the following

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier("arr_name"+positionSelected,
                        "array", rootview.getContext().getPackageName());
```

I use in spinner dropdown, get array string follow parent spinner
may help you!

Answer (score 0):

`int idInt = R.drawable.bubblegum;`

Unless there's something I'm missing here.

Comment: how does findViewById(R.drawable.bubblegum) return a ImageView?

Comment: It passes a reference to it.  `ImageView im = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bubblegum);`.  `findViewById` only accepts ID numbers from within the ViewGroup hierarchy.  You can't use the drawable id.

Comment: You are missing the fact that the id is known as a string only.

Comment: sorry, I made a mistake, I didn't want to reference that ImageView, I just tried to make an example..which was wrong. But I edited it.My problem is, like njzk2 said, that the id is known as a string only.

Answer (score 0):

if your `idString` is constant, i.e. it's doesn't change during runtime, follow DeeV's answer.
If it changes, you can take a look at [getIdentifier](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) method.